# UIButton not run action after device rotate

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

i have my button, created from storyboard:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *plusOneBtnPoisonTwo;
```

with its method:

```
- (IBAction)plusOnePlayerTwoPoison:(id)sender;
```

then I check device rotation and set new position:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

   // NSLog(@"%d", toInterfaceOrientation);

    if(!UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)){

       self.plusOneBtnPoisonTwo.center = CGPointMake(284, 406);

    }

}
```

the button moves in the new position, but the method `plusOnePlayerTwoPoison` is no more triggered...
Any Idea?
Thanks.

Comment: How are you determining the method isn't being triggered?  Are you NSLogging it?

Comment: inside the method there is a NSlog

Comment: did you connect UIButton to IBAction? Did you do it through storyboard?

Comment: Sure, in portrait all works fine, but in landscape mode  button don't work

Comment: Can u check wether the view is inside the bound of its superview. Post the screen will help to determine.

Comment: Other info: lessOneBtnPoisonTwo.bounds = {{0, 0}, {45, 45}}
lessOneBtnPoisonTwo.frame = {{530, 86}, {45, 45}} ..can help?

Comment: @Ste: Can you check whether there is a valid memory for the button after rotation?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead. Its just a guess that it may resolve your problem.

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *plusOneBtnPoisonTwo; //change to retain

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //add button action manually by code
    [plusOneBtnPoisonTwo addTarget:self action:@selector(plusOnePlayerTwoPoison:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

   // NSLog(@"%d", toInterfaceOrientation);

    if(!UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation)){

       [plusOneBtnPoisonTwo setFrame:CGRectMake(284, 406,50,100)];

    }

}
```